# How do I close the stats screen in XCOM UFO: Enemy Unknown?

Tags: xcom-ufo-defense

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong or it is a glitch. In the game XCOM UFO: Enemy Unknown, I was playing normally. I shot down a UFO, went to go kill the survivors, went into battlescape, then for some reason I decided to click on the little gold icon that brought up the stats screen.

[image]

You can see this icon here, it is labeled as [16].

Now I have this stats screen open. I cannot close it. The music is still playing, the mouse still moves around the screen, but no amount of clicking or mashing buttons has made it go away. Am I doing something wrong or is this just a glitch?

Comment: I haven't played this game in a LONG time, though I remember having this problem before. I will try to load it up and see what the issue is. Are you playing in an emulator? Blaster Launcher Or Bust!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click with the right mouse button anywhere on the screen.